# Scipy erfcinv unexpectedly blows up near 1e-16

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I've been using `scipy.special.erfcinv` to calculate Z scores from pvalues. However, when the pvalues become very small, `erfcinv` gets unexpectedly large. Any ideas?

Example:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
In [2]: from scipy.special import erfcinv
In [3]: erfcinv(2e-16) * np.sqrt(2)
Out[3]: 8.2095361516013874
In [4]: erfcinv(1e-16) * np.sqrt(2)
Out[4]: 1.7976931348623155e+308
```

I'm running python 2.6.6 with scipy 0.10.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: the closer you get to the limits of floating point arithmetic precision the weirder things happens: (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html, http://www.seas.ucla.edu/~vandenbe/103/lectures/flpt.pdf)

A little bit longer. First lets look at erfcinv function:

```
def erfcinv(y):
    return ndtri((2-y)/2.0)/sqrt(2)
```

If we take y = 2e-16:

```
In [96]: (2 - 2e-16) / 2
Out[96]: 0.9999999999999999
```

When we take y = 1e-16:

```
In [97]: (2 - 1e-16) / 2
Out[97]: 1.0
```

Now we look at ndtri:

```
x=ndtri(y) returns the argument x for which the area udnder the
Gaussian probability density function (integrated from minus infinity
to x) is equal to y.
```

Now everything should be clear, am I right? As you can suspect:

```
In [99]: ndtri(1)
Out[99]: inf
```

Your results can be a little bit different - in my case:

```
In [101]: erfcinv(1e-16) * np.sqrt(2)
Out[101]: inf
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to calculate quantiles or p-values, the you could use the stats.distributions which find in most cases the most appropriate special function, in this case I always use stats.norm.isf for the upper tail pvalue (also because I don't want to remember what erf or erfcinv is).

```
>>> for y in 10.**(-np.arange(5, 30, 2)):
    print y, special.erfcinv(y) * np.sqrt(2), stats.norm.isf(y/2.), -special.ndtri(y/2)


1e-05 4.41717341347 4.41717341347 4.41717341347
1e-07 5.32672388628 5.32672388638 5.32672388638
1e-09 6.10941019166 6.10941020487 6.10941020487
1e-11 6.80650247883 6.80650249074 6.80650249074
1e-13 7.4410077655 7.44090215064 7.44090215064
1e-15 8.01401594878 8.02685888253 8.02685888253
1e-17 inf 8.57394407672 8.57394407672
1e-19 inf 9.08895010083 9.08895010083
1e-21 inf 9.57690145543 9.57690145543
1e-23 inf 10.0416376122 10.0416376122
1e-25 inf 10.4861701796 10.4861701796
1e-27 inf 10.9129127092 10.9129127092
1e-29 inf 11.3238345582 11.3238345582
```

The floating point problems pointed out by zero323 will still show up in many other cases.

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful. I would accept this as the answer except my question was specifically asking about why erfcinv was blowing up. Nonetheless, very helpful.

Comment: The question was answered by zero323. I just wanted to point out that if you want to avoid floating point problems at a tail, then you have to use the function that is designed for that tail of the distribution (if available).